# Question about Eclipse GEF and RootEditPart

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am working on a eclipse based design editor. It's GEF based.
When I am adding root editpart to the editor , it's coming over top of my domain figures.
If I remove the rooteditpart , I am able to see my figures.

Any idea , what I may be missing ?

Thanks
Jijoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after some digging eclipse code. Need to set the bounds for figure only  then it will show up.